# MVC 5 OAuth with CORS

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, cors, google-oauth

I read several post talking about some similar problems, but I don't get yet to do this to work.

I'm doing ajax to "Account/ExternalLogin" which generates the ChallengeResult and starts the flow for the authentication with OWIN.

This is my `Startup` class :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var goath2 = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "myclientid",
            ClientSecret = "mysecret",
            Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                {
                    string redirect = context.RedirectUri;

                    const string Origin = "Origin";
                    const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";

                    // origin is https://localhost:44301                        
                    var origin = context.Request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First();


                    // header is present
                    var headerIsPresent = context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(AccessControlAllowOrigin);
                    context.Response.Redirect(redirect);                        
                }
            }
        };

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(goath2);
    }
}
```

I'm enabling CORS support whith the line `app.UserCors(CorsOptinos.AllowAll);`
And I know the header is being added to the response because I intercept the `OnApplyRedirect`event and when I look for the origin it is setted to 'localhost:443001' and the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is setted also to this value.

Nevertheless when the response is sent to the client I have the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `https://localhost:44301` is therefore not allowed
>   access.

What I'm missing here.

I could get a work around doing all this "manually" (requesting directly google from the client...) but I really want to use the OWIN middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You are making request to google from `https://localhost:44301` domain. In order that to work 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' should have `'https://localhost:44301'` origin domain in the list. So in this case it's google who need to set this domain in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Looking at the response you are getting it seems that google doesn't allow Cros origin request from your domain. To solve this I believe you need to register your domain on google https://developers.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

-> Please follow my Steps :-

- Create endpoint in your app. to handle authentication flow with google in Server-side.
- Make AJAX request in your client-side to this endpoint to Google's OAuth2 endpoint.
- Authentication flow with Google using OWIN middleware , in server-side endpoint and then after done authentication, return response to client.
- create new endpoint :- AccountController:-

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("ExternalLogin")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLogin()
  {
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback")
    };

     return await Task.FromResult(Challenge(properties, "Google"));
   }

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("ExternalLoginCallback")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
  {
      // Handle the callback after successful authentication
     var loginInfo = await 
     AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

     // Process the loginInfo as needed and return response
     // You may redirect or return a JSON response indicating success

      return Json(new { success = true, loginInfo });
    }
  ```
- Update your javascript code for new endpoint for AJAX request :-

  ```
      function initiateExternalLogin() {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/ExternalLogin',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
              // Handle success, if needed
              console.log(response);
          },
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
         // Handle error, if needed
         console.error(xhr.responseText);
         }
        });
       }
  ```
- please check authentication middleware is correctly set up in your Startup.cs file.